# convert a float to string in F#?

Tags: f#

How do I convert a float to a string in F#. I'm looking for a function with this signature:

`float -> string`

Comment: It really depends on how you want the resulting string to look. It may be more subtle than you think :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
> sprintf "%f";;
val it : (float -> string) = <fun:it@8>
```

Comment: couldn't select the answer for 11 minutes for some reason. So...I forgot about it for about a day.

Answer (score 24):

As others pointed out, there are a few options. The two simplest are calling `ToString` method and using `string` function. There is a subtle difference between the two that you should be aware of. Here is what they do on my system:

```
> sprintf "%f" 1.2;;
val it : string = "1.200000"
> string 1.2;;
val it : string = "1.2"
> 1.2.ToString();;
val it : string = "1,2"
```

The first two are different, but both make sense, but why the heck did the last one return "1,2"?

That's because I have Czech regional settings where decimal point is written as comma (doh!) So, the `string` function uses invariant culture while `ToString` uses current culture (of a thread). In some weird cultures (like Czech :-)) this can cause troubles! You can also specify this explicitly with the `ToString` method:

```
> 1.2.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);;
val it : string = "1.2"
```

So, the choice of the method will probably depend on how you want to use the string - for presentation, you should respect the OS setting, but for generating portable files, you probably want invariant culture.

Comment: Good point, I have "1,2" too :). Fun fact: the weird cultures almost stalled developement of ALGOL according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark "Decimal mark").

Comment: There is another difference between the `string` function and the `ToString` method. Try applying them to `null` and `None`. While `string` always returns an empty string, the `ToString` method crashes.

Answer (score 9):

Use the 'string' function.

```
string 6.3f
```

Comment: Additionally you have an equivalent conversion function for other basic types with functions `int`, `uint32`, `float32`, `byte`, `char`, `decimal`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
string;;
val it : (obj -> string) = <fun:it@1>
```

Comment: The signature is deceptive here, since `string` is an inline statically optimized function and, when used with float, translates into something like  `let x = 3.2 in (# "" x : float      #).ToString("g",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Constraining the signature like `(string:float->string)` is a better illustration I think.

Comment: I agree.  MSDN also list it as the casting operator.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx  I'd imagine most people would want to use sprintf "%f" so you can format the float how you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just to round out the answers:

```
(fun (x:float) -> x.ToString())
```

:)

Comment: This was fun answering just to see how fast others would post and up vote.

Comment: Might as well add in `System.Convert.ToString` if you're trying to round out the answers ;)

Comment: @gradbot: It was answered fast, but all answers ignored subtle aspects of fun cultures :-)!