# F# converting a string to a float

Tags: f#, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a simple problem that I haven't been able to figure out. I have a program that's supposed to read a float from input. Problem is it will come as string and I can't for the life of me figure out how to convert it to a float (yes I'm a complete newb).

```
let searchString = args.[0]
let myFloat = hmm hmmm hmmmm
```

Comment: To format code put four spaces before each line, or select it and press the `{}` button in the editor. For more formatting help, please refer to the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 19):

There was a related question on [conversion in the other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833722/convert-a-float-to-string-in-f). It is a bit tricky, because the floating point format depends on the current OS culture. The `float` function works on numbers in the invariant culture format (something like "3.14"). If you have float in the culture-dependent format (e.g. "3,14" in some countries), then you'll need to use `Single.Parse`.

For example, on my machine (with Czech culture settings, which uses "3,14"):

```
> float "1.1";;
val it : float = 1.1
> System.Single.Parse("1,1");;
val it : float32 = 1.10000002f
```

Both functions throw exception if called the other way round. The `Parse` method also has an overload that takes `CultureInfo` where you can specify the culture explicitly

Comment: Note that `Single` is a float32, to get a float you need to use `Double.Parse` or its safer cousin `Double.TryParse`.

Answer (score 9):

`let myFloat = float searchString`

Simple as that.

Comment: See @Thomas.  Float string representation depends on the culture.

Comment: what happens when it fails to parse ?

Comment: @fahadash `System.FormatException` is thrown.

Answer (score 7):

A `side-effect-free` parseFloat function  would look like:

```
let parseFloat s =
    match System.Double.TryParse(s) with 
    | true, n -> Some n
    | _ -> None
```

or even shorter:

```
let parseFloat s = try Some (float s) with | _ -> None
```