# Can you substitute something in a string?

Tags: string, f#

I am just looking to replace a period in my string with nothing. I am looking for a function like gsub in RStudio where you can replace an instance of something with something else entirely. In the case below, I want to take out the decimal point but retain all the numbers, even if the numbers are zeros. If you decide to index, you will have to remain aware of varying lengths of numbers.

Note: All the numbers are decimals.

Example:

```
2.02 -> 202

10.00 -> 1000

54.20 -> 5420

9995.50 -> 999550
```

Comment: you could multiply by hundred and if necessary cast to `int` but the below answer should work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[convert your float to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833722/convert-a-float-to-string-in-f) and use the 
[Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) function

Comment: You will need to apply the format string to the number of decimals you want.

Comment: those values are decimal not float. but how would you specify decimals?

Comment: Doesn't matter: `sprintf "%f"` will accept either decimals or floats. (But not ints, BTW).

Comment: For how to specify the number of decimal places, see https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/ and look for the heading "How to specify a format". Summary: `%[flags][width][.precision]f` where the most common character you want in the `flags` section is `0` to pad with leading zeroes instead of spaces.